# What is the meaning of the ending of Frontera Verde?

Tags: green-frontier

Near the end of the series *Green Frontier* (Frontera Verde), Helena confronts her enemy, the long-lived Nazi Joseph, inside the metaphysical space in which people are represented as little constellations of light. After struggling for some time,

> Helena is able to take all the light away from Joseph and seize control, which undoes or halts whatever damage Joseph was doing to the forest, and all the light then enters Helena and explodes outward.

Then things get really trippy. Helena finds herself in what appears to be a dimly-lit nightclub, where she walks through a crowd of dancing people. Then black liquid starts trickling from her fingers and facial orifices, and the camera rapidly flashes back and forth between her face and that of Joseph.

What is the meaning of this ending?